# Timer issues with Poco under ARM Linux

Tags: linux, timer, poco-libraries

I'm using Poco 1.4.4 and Debian Linux for an embebed proyect.

Launching my software from SSH terminal, everything works fine, but when I run it from init.d scripts, booting the system, the Poco Timers hangs but the rest of the programs works fine.

Inside Timer-callback functions, I try to connect to a remote HTTP server that returns me some data.

I am not sure if this is a Poco issue, a Linux one, or an error in my code.

Why launching from SSH everything works and launching from init.d don't work?
Do you have any idea?
Thanks

Comment: A shot in the dark, but could it be that networking isn't up when the callback is called?

Comment: Maybe, but I added traces at beginning and end of callback functions, with cout and flush, and I could see these messages at first execution  of every Timer. After that, timers doesn't work anymore. Anyway I will try to check network status as you say. Thanks for the idea :)

Comment: Martin, thanks for your help. Could you make an answer to rate it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A shot in the dark, but could it be that networking isn't up when the callback is called?

Answer (score 0):

As Martin said, it was a Linux service order issue.
Changing "S03MyService" name with "S05MyService", solves my problem.
Thanks.